# How to loop through numerous sub folders and find if a cell value matches a folder name using excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, directory, subdirectory

I have rows of data in excel, in which some of it is needed to path the location of the sub folders and where one certain cell in that row is what is searched for within the sub folders of the file location.

Search cell/column - `Range("E65000").End(xlUp).Value`

Sub folders location - `MAIN_PATH & "1. Invoices+BUFs - " & Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Value & "\" & Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Value & " - " & Range("AK65000").End(xlUp).Value & "\"`

So the first row is the first instance of the loop, second row comes next, then third row and so on.

If the data from a cell in column E matches that of a folder within the subfolders, then it is counted as a duplicate.

Any idea how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

`Dir()` will return an empty string if the supplied path is not found.

```
Dim subFolderLocation as String
Dim isDup as Boolean

'Loop this
If Dir(subFolderLodation & "\") = "" Then
    isDup = True
Else
    isDup = False
End If
'end loop
```

Comment: There a around 4 or 5 subfolders I am wanting to loop through. Not a specific 1

Comment: In that case, i'd set up a main loop for your conditions containing several Ifs, one for each subfolder.